# Save fragment state navigation component JAVA

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, onsaveinstancestate

I have searched for hours but I could not find a Java solution to satisfy my needing. I am using  `navigation component` where I have different `fragments` I switch between with the help of `bottom navigation bar`. Now the problem is that when I switch between the different fragments I want to save the state of previous fragment so it is not restored when I navigate back to it again. I have tried with `onSaveInstanceState` but this function is only called if the activity is will be destroyed. The question is **HOW** can I save my fragments state ?

Please awnser in `Java` as I do not understand kotlin. Many before me have asked the ave question but with no awnser...

Comment: Are you using [Navigation 2.4.0-alpha01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#2.4.0-alpha01) or higher? Those versions support multiple back stacks and saving the state of each tab.

Comment: I am using navigation_fragment and navigation_ui 2.3.4.

Comment: So...have you tried upgrading to Navigation 2.4.0-alpha02 (the latest at this time)?

Comment: I did not upgrade it but will do it today as I had full day or work yesterday. Is there anything I need to implement right after? Or just upgrading it will do the trick?

Comment: I have just upgrated it, I also added `app:restoreState= "true"
            app:popUpToSaveState="true"` but nothing happens, I am still unable to get my fragment saved.. Any idea what to do?

Comment: I have also tried that from alpha01 and is not working as well